# Access denied when trying to create folder using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: graph-api

I am new to Microsoft Graph API, and today when I was trying to create a test file in my SP test site, I got the attached error message.
[image]

I am using SharePoint admin account. I did try to go to Modify permissions tab and consent but apparently it require the global admin privilege's.

[image]

Comment: Unless you have consent given by Global admin privilege, this APIConnectors won't work. But based on this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http it doesn't look like you need those permission you have added. So I suggest you try with the example and see if it works for you.